# MalformedURLException: Protocol not found. RSS feeds on Android

Tags: android

I'm using the code to parse RSS from this link [IBM - Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html)...and I have little problem with the URL's. If I use this URL:

`static String feedUrl = "http://clarin.feedsportal.com/c/33088/f/577681/index.rss";`

It works right, but if I use this URL:

`static String feedUrl = "http://www.myworkingdomain.com/api/?m=getFeed&secID=163&lat=0&lng=0&rd=0&d=1";`

It gives me:

`07-07 19:41:30.134: E/AndroidNews(5454): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:`

I've already tried hints from other answers...but none of them help me out...
Any other solution?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your feedUrl, I assume that you want to do an HTTP GET request with parameters. I had a lot of trouble with that too, until I started using a StringBuilder and an HttpClient.

Here's some code, without exception catching:

```
                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory
                    .newInstance();
            SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
            RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
            myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            StringBuilder uriBuilder = new StringBuilder(
                    "http://myworkingdomain.com/api/");
            uriBuilder.append("?m=getFeed");
            uriBuilder.append("&secID=163");

            [...]

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.toString());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            // we assume that the response body contains the error message
            if (status != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(ostream);
                Log.e("HTTP CLIENT", ostream.toString());
            }

            InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();

            // Process feed

            InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(content);
            myInputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);
            myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();
            content.close();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've implemented your code and throws the same exception, but now I understand that the problem was when parsing the rss, not when I was getting it. Parsing the rss "link" tag, use new URL(link) and some links does note have the http:// part.